# How to set empty for missing value using tf.decode_csv

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a binary classification program using Tensorflow. The features and label are read from csv file by calling tf.decode_csv.

The sample code does work now, there are four columns in csv (the first three are features, the last would be label).  We set the default value to be 1 for the empty(missing) column.

```
record_defaults = [[1],[1], [1],[1]]
columns = tf.decode_csv(record_string, record_defaults=record_defaults)
```

Considering the training data is really sparse matrix, we do not want to replace the empty field by mean value or some other value,  we want to use algorithm that supports missing value instead.

So, I have two questions:

1: How to specify "empty" tensor instead of scalar data for tf.decode_csv function?

2: In my sample code, I use below code logic to train the model, whether does the matmul support empty tensor? Maybe the empty tensor will be treated as 0?

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2]), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```